# Trying to use simple variables with my bash script for ffmpeg but getting errors

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

When I run this like this, it works:

```
ffmpeg -re -y -i /home/video.webm -ss 2 \
-i /home/audio.ogg -map 0:0 -map 1:0  \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k \
-bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -async 1 \
-f flv "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/xxx"
```

However, when I introduce a variable I have a problem:

```
STREAM=-f flv \"rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/xxx\"

ffmpeg -re -y -i /home/video.webm -ss 2 \
-i /home/audio.ogg -map 0:0 -map 1:0  \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k \
-bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -async 1 \
$STREAM
```

When I run this, I get:

```
At least one output file must be specified
```

I've tried a number of different ways of doing this, but they all have errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
STREAM=-f flv \"rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/xxx\"
```

tries to run `flv \"rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/xxx\"` with `STREAM` environment variable set to `-f`. Didn't you get `bash: flv: command not found`?

Compare `STREAM=-f env`.

The variable is not set for the current shell and `$STREAM` expands to an empty string later. But even if you did:

```
# but don't
STREAM='-f flv "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/xxx"'
```

it wouldn't work. Unquoted `$STREAM` later [undergoes word splitting and filename generation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) and quotes that appear from variable expansion are not special to the shell that expanded the variable.

See this: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/108618) In your case a solution with an array is like:

```
STREAM=(-f flv "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/xxx")
ffmpeg … "${STREAM[@]}"
```

Also consider [lowercase names for variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).